# Can't run Emulator in Android Studio for OS X Yosemite

Tags: android, android-studio

I have edit the RAM to use by HAXM and run it

the HAXM works but nothing appears in the screen and my app is marked as offline. What can I do to make the app online?

I can see that it is offline here:

[image]

and when I try to run many devices it starts with 5554 then 5556 and 5558 and all of it are offline. How to solve this?

My emulator looks like this

[image]

Comment: try using genymotion instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Genymotion](https://www.genymotion.com/#!/store%20%22Genymotion) is an alternative emulator that is (for me and all of those that I know that use it) head and shoulders above the bundled AVD manager. I'd recommend trying that out before killing yourself trying to get the native emulator working